# unix terminal script for two directories

Tags: scripting, macos

I am fairly new to the world of programming and scripting, I have a little bit of knowledge under my belt. I am wondering if anyone would know a script for macOS terminal (which I believe is Unix) particularly with zsh syntax that would allow me to compare two directories based on the sha256 hash values of the files in the two directories and echo a simple message such as "folders are ==" if all the all the hashes match and "folder are !=" if they don't appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you want included in the sha256 sum and the comparison? The contents of regular files? The names of the files? Of all the files including non-regular ones? The metadata (ownership, permissions, ACLs, symlink targets, etc)?

Comment: Is it about git?

Comment: What have you written so far? Please show us what you have already so we don't waste your time, or ours, with approaches you have already tried.

Comment: so far I don't have anything written though I have been consulting GPT3 for an idea so I know I could hash the folder save it as two text files than use the diff command to asses the differences though I know terminal script is limited in functions to say python which im currently learining

Comment: if anyone can tell me if this what is wrong with the following code I ran it in a online unix shell (it ran a exit code '0' which from my understanding means the code ran) should l be saving and running it as a .sh or a .zsh file or does it make a difference.cd ~/Users/alekburt/Desktop/Hash\ Archive\ Folder
find . -type f -exec shasum -a 256 {} \; > Test_Doc1.txt
exit
find . -type f -exec shasum -a 256 {} \; > Test_Doc2.txt
exit
diff Testing_Doc1.txt Testing_Doc2.txt
if Testing_Doc1 == Testing_Doc2 echo 'folder are ==' 
else 
echo 'Folder !='
fi